# why I have different behaviour for swicthAll

Tags: typescript, rxjs

```
let obs = from([1,2,4]);
let newObs = (o) => of(o).pipe(delay(1000));
obs.pipe(
    map(s => 
      {
        return newObs(s)
      }
      ),
    switchAll()
    ).subscribe(s => console.log(s));
```

gives me output

```
4
```

However, If I dont use delay in newObs

```
let obs = from([1,2,4]);
let newObs = (o) => of(o);
obs.pipe(
    map(s => 
      {
        return newObs(s)
      }
      ),
    switchAll()
    ).subscribe(s => console.log(s));
```

gives me output

```
1
2
4
```

Why is this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the way you have set Observable up **in the second example everything is synchronous**. `from([1,2,4])` will emit items one by one and you are mapping single item to the `of(item)`, which is still synchronous. To summarize, in this example `switchAll` is not doing much, each item will be emitted synchronously to the `subscribe`.

As for the first example, you introduced delay via `of(o).pipe(delay(1000))` and now it's asynchronous. Besides the fact that it is asynchronous let's have a look at the Observable Streams. After `map` you have 3 Observables, that will emit value in exactly 1 second after being subscribed.  What `switchAll` does in general is that, whenever new Observable arrives, it subscribes to the new Observable and discards the old one.

In your example all 3 Observables arrive at the same time one by one, thus `switchAll` will subscribe to first one, then to the second one and discard the first one, finally subscribe to the third one and discard the second one. In this process none of the Observables have emitted anything, but in one second the third Observable will emit the value and you will see the console log.

See [Official Documentation for switchAll](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchAll)